# How to use Huggingface Data Collator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface-datasets

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8PmhEIXhBvI) which comes with [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/master/course/videos/mlm_processing.ipynb).

I plan to use Tensorflow for my project, so I followed [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/-RPeakdlHYo?t=67) and added the line

```
tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets["train"].to_tf_dataset(columns=["input_ids"], shuffle=True, batch_size=16, collate_fn=data_collator)
```

to the end of the notebook.

However, when I ran it, I got the following error:
`RuntimeError: Index put requires the source and destination dtypes match, got Float for the destination and Long for the source.`

**Why didn't this work? How can I use the collator?**

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not your code, but how the collator is set up. (It's set up to not use Tensorflow by default.)

If you look at [this](https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/use_dataset), you'll see that their collator uses the `return_tensors="tf"` argument. If you add this to your collator, your code for using the collator will work.

In short, your collator creation should look like

```
data_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer, mlm_probability=0.15, return_tensors="tf")
```

This will fix the issue.